# I wanna use Join with PDO But There is a Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanna use join with PDO but there is an error. I research other questions but I don't understand :( My query and error is;

**ERROR**

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /ssd4/muhtesemciftlik/public_html/referans.php on line 72

**MY QUERY**

```
<?php
    $id=2
    $query = $db->query("SELECT ref_urun,ref_tl FROM degerler INNER JOIN kullanicilar ON kullanicilar.ref = degerler.kullanici WHERE kullanicilar.ref = {'$id'}", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if ( $query->rowCount() ) { //kayıt varsa

                      foreach( $query as $row ){
                          echo "
                            <tr>
                              <th style=\"width: 10px\">#</th>
                              <th>".$row["kullanici"]."</th>
                              <th>".$row["ref_urun"]."</th>
                              <th>".$row["ref_tl"]."</th>
                            </tr>
                          ";
                      }

                    }
?>
```

Comment: try changing `{'$id'}` to `'{$id}'`

Comment: syntatically speaking; your posted code contains more than one error; IF that's your real code or were just in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT ref_urun,ref_tl FROM degerler INNER JOIN kullanicilar ON kullanicilar.ref = degerler.kullanici WHERE kullanicilar.ref = {'$id'}", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT ref_urun,ref_tl FROM degerler INNER JOIN kullanicilar ON kullanicilar.ref = degerler.kullanici WHERE kullanicilar.ref = '{$id}'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: The real question here is "why" should they change it to that? RamRaider already answered it in comments which was just that; a comment. Answers should explain the reason.